# Can an internal SSD be used as a removable storage device?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have a Sandisk SSD drive that I bought for about $70 but decided to not install it in my PC. So I guess my question is, can I use it essentially as a thumb drive?

Comment: Yes.  Buy an enclosure.

Comment: USB adapters are sold for this very purpose. I have one myself, though I hardly use it. And it's not in an enclosure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB 3.0 SSD drives are already being manufactured in the thumb drive form factor with capacities ranging from 32GB-256GB. The performance of SSD thumb drives is said to be very fast. Regarding your SSD drive, it would be possible to buy an inexpensive external 2.5" hard drive enclosure for it and use the SSD as an external hard drive.